# How can we invoke a segmentation fault/core dump for any daemon process without code access?

Tags: unix, aix, unix-socket

How can we invoke a segmentation fault/core dump for any daemon process without code access ?

Comment: Send it a `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS` signal.

Comment: from the command line: `kill -segv (your-daemon-pid)`

Answer (score 2):

AIX has a command 'gencore' [1] that you can use to request a core dump without a segmentation fault or any other interruption.

[1] https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/gencore.htm

Answer (score 0):

kill -11  of the process or the daemon, when segmentation fault 
happens OS will do core dump. Here we are faking a segmentation 
fault by sending the SIGSEGV( 11 ) to it. 
Refer to /usr/include/sys/signal.h to check the number of 
the signal.